# Emberjs/Chrome/FFox: numeric Access-Control-Request-Headers in preflight

Tags: javascript, django, google-chrome, ember.js

I'm developing an Emberjs front-end that should use a django rest framework backend. I'm just starting out and working on the authentication using JWT/Javascript Web Tokens.

This is what I've done:

- On the backend (currently django's development server for obvious reasons) I'm allowing all origins (since ember-cli runs at localhost:4200 and django at :8000). I.e. the origin is being accepted.
- The serverTokenEndpoint is correctly set in Emberjs
- I can add manually the numeric headers on django to be accepted, but I don't want to unless I know why I should allow them.

The problem I see now is the following:

- On chrome, the preflight OPTIONS request to the backend includes a request to allow headers 0 to 9.
- On Firefox, the preflight OPTIONS request to the backend includes a request to allow headers 0 to 4.

These headers are not allowed by the backend and I could not find a source for this request nor what their meaning should/could be.

Again, this is part of the OPTIONS request from Firefox:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: 0,1,2,3,4,content-type
```

And this from Chrome:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, accept, content-type
```

My question: Why is requested if these numeric headers can be included? Where do they come from (ember? the browser itself?) and what do they mean? And, ideally, how can I get rid of them?

Comment: the headers come from the request

Comment: ok yes. that's obviously the case. But why does it check if headers 0..9 are accepted? I've never encountered a numeric header before... I edited the question, I hope it's more precise now.

Comment: I can tell you, no browser should pre-flight a CORS request with `access-control-request-headers` unless those request headers were set in the xmlhttprequest object using `setRequestHeader` - I'm actually surprised to see content-type and accept in that list!

Comment: well, content-type and accept make sense, I guess. since that's what the proper request will send if it passes preflight, right?
So you'd say this is coming from JS, i.e. Emberjs, and not the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out what the problem was. I mixed code from [ember-simple-auth's readme](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth#readme) that uses Oauth2 for authentication with [ember-simple-auth-token's approach](https://github.com/jpadilla/ember-simple-auth-token).

For Oauth2, the readme suggests to unpack the credentials into two variables and pass these to the authenticate function:

```
let { identification, password } = this.getProperties('identification', 'password');
this.get('session').authenticate('authenticator:oauth2', identification, password).catch((reason) => {
  this.set('errorMessage', reason.error || reason);
});
```

whereas the token version does not unpack the credentials:

```
var credentials = this.getProperties('identification', 'password'),
authenticator = 'authenticator:jwt';
this.get('session').authenticate(authenticator, credentials);
```

Turns out that the authenticate function of the jwt authenticator takes up to three arguments, the third being headers. The way I mixed the code resulted in my password decomposed into the numeric values for some reason. In the firefox snippet i posted I used a different password, that's why the values only go to 4, not 9.

By not unpacking the credentials preflight succeeds.